# Hacer funcionar un boton javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estimados commo puedo hacer que el boton"buscarcito" pueda imprimir el texto de los options?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_id" >
<option selected disabled>seleccione:</option>
<option value="valor_1">opcion 1</option>
<option value="valor_2">opcion 2</option>
</select>
<button id="buscarcito" onclick="miFuncion($(this).val());" >Buscador</button>
<input type="text" id="valor_select">
<script>
function miFuncion(select_id){
$("#valor_select").val(select_id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A como te entiendo y por el codigo que expones buscas hacer algo a si

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <select id="select_id" >
   <option selected disabled>seleccione:</option>
   <option value="valor_1">opcion 1</option>
   <option value="valor_2">opcion 2</option>
 </select>
 <button id="buscarcito" onclick="miFuncion($('#select_id').val());">Buscador</button>
  <input type="text" id="valor_select">
 <script>
   function miFuncion(select_id){
     $("#valor_select").val(select_id);
   }
 </script>
```

ya que tu al dejar tu `onclick="miFuncion($(this).val());"` no le mandas ningún valor porque estas diciendo 'this' osea este objeto su valor lo vas a imprimir en el input con el id="valor_select" el cual no tiene.

Answer (score 1):

Quizá esto pueda servirte:

```html
<select id="select_id" >
    <option selected disabled>seleccione:</option>
    <option value="valor_1">opcion 1</option>
    <option value="valor_2">opcion 2</option>
</select>
<button id="buscarcito" onclick="miFuncion();">Buscador</button>
<input type="text" id="valor_select">

<script>
    function miFuncion(){
      selectx = document.getElementById('select_id').value;
      inputx = document.getElementById('valor_select').value = selectx;
    }
</script>
```

Es sin usar **jQuery**, puro **Javascript**